# Handling Datetime in Cypher for neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the datetime field in the property of the node, I can return the values, but not working for WHERE clause
[image]

If I use where for specific date its not returning
[image]

[image]

Also i want to return the last 3 days transaction, i tried datetime() minus datetime('2020-03-02T00:01:44.68Z'), i couldn't return

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Found it, 
datetime field need casting to filter the date or datetime
Thanks

[image]

[image]

one thing i couldn't is to get the last 3 days, i have to check the t.TxnDateTime and the current datetime() difference of 3 days

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/operators/#cypher-ordering), comparisons can only be done between temporal instant values of the same type. For example, a `date` cannot be compared to a `datetime`, but it can be compared to another `date`.

Also, you can use an appropriate [duration function](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/duration/#functions-duration-computing) (such as `duration.inSeconds()`) to subtract 2 temporal values, creating a `duration`. And you can then [access a component](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-accessing-components-durations) of that `duration` using an appropriate property (such as `seconds`).

For example, this query:

```
WITH duration.inSeconds(
  date({year:2000, month:1, day:1}),
  date({year:2000, month:1, day:2})) AS durationInSeconds
RETURN durationInSeconds, durationInSeconds.seconds
```

returns:

```
╒═══════════════════╤═══════════════════════════╕
│"durationInSeconds"│"durationInSeconds.seconds"│
╞═══════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│"P0M0DT86400S"     │86400                      │
└───────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘
```